# Terminating input using Ctrl-D character not working

Tags: perl, cygwin

I attempted to write a Perl script to take user input. I am 
on Windows 8 and Cygwin.

When I try to run my code it expects user input as it should, but when I attempt to press *Ctrl-D* the program still tries to accept input instead of signalling the end of input.

Here is my code below. Why is this the case? Is there a way I can overcome this without switching away from Cygwin? I do not want to press *Ctrl-Z* or *Ctrl-C* as I don't want to stop the execution of the program.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

while ( $line = <> ) {
    print $line;
}
```

Comment: It's strange that you haven't even *tried* Ctrl-Z before asking for help

Comment: @Jason J, If you're using a cygwin build of Perl, you'd use Ctrl-D since that signals EOF on unix systems like cygwin. But you appear to be using a Windows build of Perl (ActivePerl? Strawberry Perl?). Ctrl-Z signals EOF in Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows you have to use <kbd>CTRL-Z</kbd> instead of <kbd>CTRL-D</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But wouldn't that stop my program?

Comment: CTRL+Z on Windows act as EOF control code, hence it's used to signal an end-of-file. It won't stop your program.